# My React app works fine in Chrome but not in firefox

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react-redux app that is running fine in chrome but in firefox it is showing blank screen.

For the same request in the network tab, firefox is giving status code 304 whereas in chrome it's 200.

As I am using the redux store,I have used below code for creating redux store.

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(rootReducer,composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

If I use below code for creating composeEnhancers then it's value is coming "undefined " and code fails in firefox .But this also works fine in chrome.

```
const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ :null || compose;
```

Firefox error:

> Download the React DevTools for a better development experience
>
> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: You can try this `const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ :compose;`

Comment: Did you call asynchronous request in `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: from second error, It seems like you have sent an Async request and till the time it has returned your component has unmounted, or you have registered global even listeners like window resize event and they get fired and after the component has unmounted

Comment: @ravibagul91 using the code mentioned by you I am getting " TypeError: composeEnhancers is not a function"

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhedri  : I am not making any request in componentWillUnmount. I have not used it anywhere in the code

Comment: @Harsh kurra :  I am not making any request in componentWillUnmount. I have not used it anywhere in the code –

Comment: This error is not pointing you to componentWillUnmount lifecycle but I think you have somewhere called and asynchronus operation and you didn't destroyed it when the component will unmount. It's very often error it this situation

Comment: @Freestyle09 but how is it possible that this thing works in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: Maybe some developer tools from firefox block you to have any memory leaks but in chrome you don't have installed any extensions that points you that error ? Have you that app in any server that can I check it in my browers ?

Answer (score 0):

> This warning(s) usually shows up when **this.setState()** is called in
>   a component even though the component got already unmounted.

The unmounting can happen for different cases:

- You don’t render a component anymore due to React’s conditional rendering.
- You navigate away from a component by using a library such as React Router.

> When not rendering the component anymore, it can still happen that
>   this.setState() is called if you have done **asynchronous business
>   logic** in your component and updated the local state of the component
>   afterward.

The following cases are the most common causes:

- You made an asynchronous request to an API, the request (e.g. Promise) isn’t resolved yet, but you unmount the component.
- Then the request resolves, this.setState() is called to set the new state, but it hits an unmounted component.
- You have a listener in your component, but didn’t remove it on componentWillUnmount(). * Then the listener may be triggered when the component unmounted.
- You have an interval (e.g. setInterval) set up in your component and within the interval this.setState() is called.
- If you forgot to remove the interval on componentWillUnmount(), you will update state on an unmounted component again.

```js
class News extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      news: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    axios
      .get('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=react')
      .then(result => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
          this.setState({
            news: result.data.hits,
          });
        }
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Try implementing this approach.

*P.S: Different browsers behave differently for .js and .css functions. Try using more cross-browsers functions.*